# Non-recursive approach to the Rod-Cutting

Tags: java, algorithm

I've given the Rod-Cutting Problem a go with a non-recursive approach that use a cache instead, with a bottom up approach. For anyone who hasn't heard about the Rod-Cutting problem, it's defined as follows:

> Serling Enterprises buys long steel rods and cuts them into shorter
>   rods, which it then sells. Each cut is free. The management of Serling
>   Enterprises wants to know the best way to cut up the rods. We assume
>   that we know, for i = 1, 2, ..., the price pi in dollars that Serling
>   Enterprises charges for a rod of length i inches. Rod lengths are
>   always an integral number of inches. Given a rod of length n inches
>   and a table of prices p<sub>i</sub> for i = 1, 2, ..., n determine the maximum
>   revenue obtainable by cutting up the rod and selling the pieces. Note
>   that if the price p<sub>n</sub> for a rod of length n is large enough, an optimal
>   solution may require no cutting at all.

```
public static int[] prices = new int[]{1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Best Price Check #1
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " => " + bestPrice(i));
    }

}

public static int bestPrice(int n) {

    // This works like a cache
    int[] maxPrices = new int[n+1];

    // The trick here is to work from the bottom up
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        int max_price = prices[i-1]; // Without cuts

        // Try all cuts length with combo from existing cache
        for (int j = 1; j <  i; j++) {
            max_price = Math.max(max_price, maxPrices[i-j] + prices[j-1]);
        }
        maxPrices[i] = max_price;
    }

    return maxPrices[n];

}
```

Comment: You might want to change `pi` to `p<sub>i</sub>`, since I doubt we're talking about π.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm itself seems to have no problems. It's [Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) and I wouldn't call the `int[] maxPrices` cache. Cache is something used for speed only, you can clear it anytime and everything must still work.

For example, a straightforward recursive solution to this problem would be damn slow because of recomputing values again and again. It could be made much faster using a cache.

```
 public static int[] prices = new int[]{1,5,8,9,10,17,17,20};
```

This way you lose any chance to make it more flexible. You class has two functions: It's both the *computing core* and the *main class*. That's fine for a small class, but even then you should separate the tasks.

For the main class, something like

```
private static final int[] PRICES = new int[] {1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20};
```

Here, `static final` is the way how constants get declared in Java. `PRICES` is uppercase as a constant should be. And there's a space after each comma.

For the core, pass it explicitly to the `bestPrice` method. In more complicated cases, you could use an instance field for this.

---

`max_price` should be `maxPrice` in Java. No underscores except in constants.

Comment: Thanks for the variable naming tips - something great to watch out in the future.  And yeah I guess you right with not calling it a cache. Also are you saying that a recursive solution with a cache is a more flexible solution and thus preferred?

Comment: @Paul "recursive solution with a cache is a more flexible solution" - just sometimes. For what you did, it has no advantage. Computing "everything upwards" like you did is also usually most efficient. +++ But there are cases when you don't know what values are needed for the final result. Imagine something like `f(x,y) = f(x/2, y) + f(x, y - y/3 - 1)` and compute `f(a, a)` for `a = (long) 1e18`. No idea, if it's feasible (probably yes), but precomputing a 2D table with `1e36` elements surely is not.